# Create WebAPI post from Console to include $type in json data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating objects and posting them to a webapi.  Basically I just can't get the darn things to serialize so as to include the $type info in the json.  The following is the code I'm attempting to write.  Afterwards is the json I would expect.

```
       var cds = new List<CreditDefaultSwaps>()
        {
            new CreditDefaultSwaps() { ModelNumber = "SP8A1ETA", BrokerSpread = 0},
            new CreditDefaultSwaps() { ModelNumber = "SP3A0TU1", BrokerSpread = 0},
            new CreditDefaultSwaps() { ModelNumber = "SP4A102V", BrokerSpread = 0}
        };

        var client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/BloombergWebAPI/api/")};

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // set up request object
        var oContract = new WebApiDataServiceRequest
        {
            RequestType = ReferenceDataRequestServiceTypes.ReferenceDataRequest,
            SwapType = BloombergWebAPIMarshal.SwapType.CDS,
            SecurityList = cds
        };

        Tried something like this and the var content was formatted as I would expect
        however I couldn't post the data using postasjsonasync

        //var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oContract, Formatting.Indented,
        //    new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects });

           Console.ReadLine();

        var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("bloombergapi/processbloombergrequest", oContract).Result;
```

The following is the json I'm trying to post.  What am I missing in the above code, I'm sure it's something silly.

```
   {
      "$type": "BloombergWebAPIMarshal.WebApiDataServiceRequest, BloombergWebAPIMarshal",
      "RequestType": 3,
      "SwapType": 1,
      "SecurityList": [
        {
          "$type": "BloombergWebAPIMarshal.CreditDefaultSwaps, BloombergWebAPIMarshal",
          "ModelNumber": "SP8A1ETA",
          "BrokerSpread": 0
        },
        {
          "$type": "BloombergWebAPIMarshal.CreditDefaultSwaps, BloombergWebAPIMarshal",
          "ModelNumber": "SP3A0TU1",
          "BrokerSpread": 0
        },
        {
          "$type": "BloombergWebAPIMarshal.CreditDefaultSwaps, BloombergWebAPIMarshal",
          "ModelNumber": "SP4A102V",
          "BrokerSpread": 0
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Created another overload Used this call to produce proper request:

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("processbloombergrequest", oContract, TypeNameHandling.Objects).Result
```

This is the new overload

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string requestUri, T value, TypeNameHandling typeNameHandling)
{

    return client.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(requestUri, value, CancellationToken.None, typeNameHandling);
}

public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string requestUri, T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TypeNameHandling typeNameHandling)
{
    var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            TypeNameHandling = typeNameHandling
        }
    };

    return client.PostAsync<T>(requestUri, value, formatter, cancellationToken);
}
```