# WCF will not accept an object with a datetime property (400 bad request)

Tags: c#, json, wpf, wcf, datetime

This is my first post on SO, so please forgive me if I don't provide enough information. I have a WPF app that is trying to send an `EmployeeLogin` object that contains a `DateTime` property to my WCF web service and I keep getting a 400 bad request error when calling this `EmployeeLogIn()` method. I have searched so many places for an answer, but I can't get a direct answer to my specific situation.

So my main question is: Does sending an object with a `DateTime` property that has been set via the method below automatically get converted to the JSON format (`\/Date(1237951967000)\/`) and get accepted by the wcf service as a valid `DateTime` property, or does it convert it to the above JSON string and get passed to the method as a string?

EDITv2: My WPF app is not sending this `DateTime` object in the above correct format and instead sending it as `"2017-08-11T13:47:55.2187627-04:00"` and I can't figure out a way to get it into the correct `DateTime` format. I can get it into this format as a string, but for the reasons stated at the end of this post, that would be a last-ditch effort.

> ```
> EmployeeLogin EmpLogin = new EmployeeLogin
>             {
>                 EmployeeID = (int)UserName,
>                 Password = Pass,
>                 Latitude = 33.45,
>                 Longitude = 134.44,
>                 TimeIn = DateTime.Now
>             };
> HttpResponseMessage response = await
> Client.PostAsJsonAsync(string.Format(@"{0}{1}", URL, method),
> EmpLogin);
> ```

Where EmployeeLogin is defined below:

> ```
> [DataContract]
> public class EmployeeLogin
> {
>     [DataMember]
>     public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
>     [DataMember]
>     public string Password { get; set; }
>     [DataMember]
>     public DateTime TimeIn { get; set; }
>     [DataMember]
>     public Nullable<double> Latitude { get; set; }
>     [DataMember]
>     public Nullable<double> Longitude { get; set; }
> }
> ```

and the EmployeeLogIn method signature is as follows:

> ```
> [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
> ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle =
> WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse)]
>     [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Data")]
>     [OperationContract]
>     List<int> EmployeeLogIn(EmployeeLogin e);
> ```

I know the easiest solution is to change the `DateTime` to a `string` property and convert it back to a `DateTime` on the web service side, but I'm trying not to make any changes to the web service unless absolutely necessary. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are wanting to know how WCF serializes and deserializes DateTime, write a WCF endpoint that returns a DateTime.  Use Fiddler or its equivalent to examine the response.  Fiddler (or its equivalent) can also help you to understand exactly how `PostAsJsonAsync` is serializing your DateTime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, `PostAsJsonAsync` is definitely formatting the `DateTime` incorrectly according to Fiddler: `{"EmployeeID":6,"Password":"6490","TimeIn":"2017-08-11T13:47:55.2187627-04:00","Latitude":33.45,"Longitude":134.44}` So how do I get the `DateTime` into the proper format?

Comment: I figured it out finally! The answer to the question in the linked post explains the problem perfectly and offers a solution that worked just as perfectly for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072965/webservice-not-deserializing-some-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally found the answer to this question after weeks of searching. The problem I was experiencing is explained fully in the post linked to below, and the solution to the problem that is offered in the post worked perfectly for me. Here is the [post with the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072965/webservice-not-deserializing-some-objects) to my problem.